# ERROR ObjectUnsubscribedErrorImpl in using angular-datatable using angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, datatable

i am trying to display Datatable in an model window. 
First time i can able to view the screen as expected. After closing the model window, Now i am trying to view the result in model window but from the second time the Datatable doesn't shows the search box, pagination.

can some one help me to fix this issue.

Expected: [image: click to view]

second: [image: click to view]

Error: [image: Click to View Error]

**my.component.ts**

```
    @ViewChild(DataTableDirective)
    dtElement: DataTableDirective;

    dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};

    // We use this trigger because fetching the list of persons can be quite long,
    // thus we ensure the data is fetched before rendering
    dtTrigger: Subject<any> = new Subject();

    ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getQueryResult(this.saveIteratorParams).subscribe( data => {
          if (data.success !== false) {
            this.queryViewResultL = data.payload;

            this.tableDataList = data.payload.molResults;

            if (this.tableDataList !== null || this.tableDataList !== undefined) {
              this.theadData = Object.keys(this.tableDataList[0]);

              // Calling the DT trigger to manually render the table
              this.dtOptions = {
                pagingType: 'full_numbers',
                pageLength: 10
              };

              this.dtTrigger.next();
            }
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.dtTrigger.next();
        // console.log('ngAfterViewInit');
      }

      rerender(): void {
        this.dtElement.dtInstance.then((dtInstance: DataTables.Api) => {
          // Destroy the table first
          dtInstance.destroy();
          // Call the dtTrigger to rerender again
          this.dtTrigger.next();
          // if (this.dtTrigger.observers) { this.dtTrigger.next(); }
        });
      }

      ngOnDestroy(): void {
        // Do not forget to unsubscribe the event
        this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
        console.log('this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe()', this.dtTrigger);

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact issue in your case. I received the same error while I was working on my project. This error usually signifies that the subscriber or the main method is modified by some other code which led it to unsubscribing. You can debug it using the developer tools. In the right side, you will find the watch. Write the expression name there for example this.service.getQueryResult(this.saveIteratorParams). From this code, I think the destroy is interrupting it.

Comment: Thanks, i tried as you said, Even if use unsubscribe, Still its not working. Can you prefer some debug tool.

Comment: I personally used the debug tool/developer tool of chrome only. Is there anywhere else where the object is getting modified? I may be able to help if you can provide a jsfiddle or something to recreate this issue.